# running commands on physical drives on different backplane with megacli

Tags: linux, raid, hardware-raid, megaraid, megacli

So when I run "MegaCli64 -PDlist -aALL -NoLog | egrep 'Slot|state|Inquiry|Enclosure'" to grab a list of disks and their status. I can see a total of 36 disks. The issue is that they have the same slot number and the megacli says to reference the disks by EnclosureID and SlotNumber. How do I reference the different disks with the same slot number and enclosureID::

## IE ::

```
Slot Number: 8
Enclosure position: 0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
Inquiry Data:      WD-WCAVY6576736WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3B0                   04.01G01
Enclosure Device ID: 37
Slot Number: 8
Enclosure position: 0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Inquiry Data:      WD-WCAVY6614815WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3B0                   04.01G01
Enclosure Device ID: 37
Slot Number: 9
Enclosure position: 0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
Inquiry Data:      WD-WCAVY6623834WDC WD2002FYPS-02W3B0                   04.01G01
Enclosure Device ID: 37
Slot Number: 9
Enclosure position: 0
Firmware state: Rebuild
Inquiry Data:      WD-WMAY00411420WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0B0                   01.01D01
```

As we can see the above shows two disks with different serials for slots 8 and 9 with different states.

If i try to check the rebuild status::

```
# MegaCli64 -pdrbld -progdsply -physdrv[37:9] -aall

Device(Encl-37 Slot-9) is not in rebuild process

Clearly the drive is indeed in a rebuild process.
```

The log also shows that the drive is rebuilding. It has been rebuilding most of the day and I am just trying to find out the status.

I looked around and I didn't see any relevant previous questions outside of "MegaCli64 -PDInfo shows drive but other commands says device does not exist" which seems to be dead.

I am hoping a bit more verbosity may yield a better result than the other thread.

---

Thanks toppledwagon, I tried that too specifying -a0 -a1 and -a2. There is only adapter but I thought it couldn't hurt.

```
root@bioc-aoe1-rglab:/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli# ./MegaCli64 -CfgDsply -a0 | head

==============================================================================
Adapter: 0
Product Name: Supermicro SMC2108
Memory: 512MB
BBU: Present
Serial No: 
==============================================================================
Number of DISK GROUPS: 2

root@bioc-aoe1-rglab:/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli# ./MegaCli64 -CfgDsply -a1 | head

User specified controller is not present.
Failed to get CpController object.

Exit Code: 0x01
root@bioc-aoe1-rglab:/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli# ./MegaCli64 -CfgDsply -a2 | head

User specified controller is not present.
Failed to get CpController object.
Exit Code: 0x01
```

Comment: MegaCli is the *least usable* command line utility ever devised.

Comment: I like the tool compared to arcconf or tw_cli. The flags allow me to quickly get what I need. The issue is I have a 36 disk supermicro chassis with 24 in the front and 12 in the back. The megacli utility is giving the 12 in back the same slot number as the front.

Comment: Is there more than one adapter on thus host?  All of your commands use -aall. Maybe try -a0 or -a1.